# LWF status when LAN Wire disconnected or re-connected

Tags: ndis, filter-driver

In Miniport drivers we have two status indications(NDIS_STATUS_MEDIA_CONNECT/NDIS_STATUS_MEDIA_DISCONNECT) to know whether LAN is disconnected or not.

Can we use the same indications in LWF to know the status of Media associated with LAN. I have two scenarios that I want get the indications or handles for.

1. When Wire connected to NIC is pulled and re-connected.
2. When two PC's are connected through a wire, I will power down the other PC where LWF is not running.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Drivers written in the last 10 years should not use NDIS_STATUS_MEDIA_CONNECT or NDIS_STATUS_MEDIA_DISCONECT.  Those were retired with NDIS 5.x.  Instead, use NDIS_STATUS_LINK_STATE.

Filter drivers may listen for NDIS_STATUS_LINK_STATE.  They can also query the current link state at any time, by issuing OID_GEN_LINK_STATE.

If your filter originates NBLs, I encourage you to monitor the link state.  It's just a waste of CPU cycles to try and originate NBLs when the link is down -- the packets will just get returned to you.